# How to Translate C# Expression to Custom Nested (recursive) Class structure?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func, expressionvisitor

I've custom Query Class which will be used to build query with help of lambda expression like below

```
var query = new Query("Person").Where<Person>(p =>
(p.Name == "Maulik" && (p.Id == 2 || p.Age == 30)) || (p.Id == 2 && p.Name == "Maulik"));
```

By Implementing `ExpressionVisitor` based on this reference [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1241363/Expression-Tree-Traversal-Via-Visitor-Pattern-in-P) class I'm able to get translated query into string format as below

`(((Name EqualTo "Maulik") AND ((Id EqualTo 2) OR (Age EqualTo 30))) OR ((Id EqualTo 2) AND (Name EqualTo 'Maulik')))`

But, I want to translate above expression to my custom nested classes

```
public class Expression
{
    public List<Expression> Filters { get; } // Nested expression
    public Operator Operator { get; set; } //e.g AND/OR
    public List<Condition> Conditions { get; } // One Expression can have many conditions
}

public class Condition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Operator Operator { get; set; } //e.g <,> ==, != etc
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Where Expression means: `(A > 5 && A < 10)` and Condition means inner most criteria `A > 5`

*By Nested I mean, where one expression can have child expression, which can also have sub child expression and so on, and for each expression there can be multiple conditions.*

Reason to convert into this kind of structure is to handle various SQL/NoSQL provider, from this kind of class structure will be creating separate queries for all different providers, so this class structure can't be changed entirely.

This class structure is created to maintain parentheses sequence based on AND and OR condition of query, so accordingly same level condition can be club with single expression.

I'm looking for any kind of generic mapping which can help here to translate expression to nested class structure.

What will be best way of converting expression to custom nested class structure? Please share if any implementation example available. I couldn't find any relevant example yet.

Comment: If you use an ORM like Entity Framework or even just Linq to SQL then this is handled for you. Is it really necessary to reinvent this wheel? It can be done but the complex array of nested and sub-correlated expressions and projections means that to do it properly you would have recreated a Db Provider for EF, or you get run time errors once the Linq is anything other than the most basic criteria

Comment: Yes need to do this, as need to support various Sql/NoSql providers, so this middle class layer will be used to translate into DB specific query

Comment: @Maulik And none of those DBs have existing LINQ providers?

Comment: @Servy not all but few of them including NoSql don't have LINQ providers

Comment: @Maulik Then why are you writing a query provider for all of them?  Use the existing providers you have for every DB that supports it.

Comment: @Servy Initially I thought to write individual query provider for all of them, but then in team we decided to add this common layer, which can further translated into separate providers as required, to handle complexity at single layer rather than at each provider, so need solution to translate expression to current class structure

Answer (score 0):

I think that your classes do not reflect the structure of expressions right. Let me use [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) to write down a possible syntax of such expressions (without claim of completeness):

```
Expression = Term { ("AND" | "OR") Term }.
Term = "(" Expression ")" | Comparison.
Comparison = name ("=" | "!=" | "<" ...) Value.
Value = stringConstant | number.
```

One important thing we see, is that a `Term` can be either an `Expression` or a `Comparison`. This means that we must be able to plug in the one or the other to both sides of an `AND` or `OR`. Example: `Name = "Maulik" AND (Id = 2 OR Id = 3)`. To the left of the `AND` we have a comparison, to the right an expression.

Therefore, we must make these two things assignment compatible, e.g., by deriving them from the same base class.

```cs
public abstract class Term
{
}

public Expression : Term
{
    public Term FirstTerm { get; set; }
    public List<(BooleanOperator operator, Term term)> SucceedingTerms { get; } = new();
}

public Comparison : Term
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ComparisonOperator Operator { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Another important fact is that the syntax is recursive. I.e., an expression contains terms and terms can contain another expression. This is necessary to be able to represent parenthesized expressions with multiple levels of nesting.

This recursive nature of the syntax has two consequences:

1. The class structure must allow recursive structures. This is given by the fact that the `Expression` class has a list containing `Term`s and those can be `Expression`s again.
2. The parser shown later must be recursive. It contains indirect recursive calls (`ParseExpression` calls `ParseTerm` and `ParseTerm` calls `ParseExpression`).

Note that I am using [ValueTulpes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) as list element consisting of an operator and a term.

---

Now, to the conversion itself. You need a compiler. Either

- Build your own custom compiler by hand.
  [Niklaus Wirth's book Compiler Construction (2 PDFs)](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/CompilerConstruction/) is an introduction to the theory and the techniques of compiler construction. It gives you a general idea of what a compiler is and what it does.
- Use a tool or library to generate a compiler: for example [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/download.html).

---

Since the syntax is simple, you might dare to write the compiler yourself.

Divide the task into lexical analysis (done by a lexer) and syntax analysis (done by a parser). Besides analyzing the syntax, the parser also creates the required data structure as output. The lexer just returns a stream of symbols. E.g.

```cs
enum Symbol { EndOfInput, LeftPar, RightPar, AndOperator, OrOperator, Identifier, Number,
              StringLiteral, ...}
```

```cs
private string _input;
private int _currentPos;
private string _identifier;
private string _stringValue;
private decimal _number;
private Symbol _symbol;

/// Does the lexical analysis.
private void GetSymbol()
{
    // Get next `_symbol` (and associated variables) from `_input` at `_currentPos` and
    // update `_currentPos`.
}
```

Using this basic infrastructure, you can create the parser. The parser consists of methods closely reflecting the structure of the syntax (as given in EBNF above).

```cs
// Expression = Term { ("AND" | "OR") Term }.
void Expression ParseExpression()
{
    var expression = new Expression();
    expression.FirstTerm = ParseTerm();
    while (_symbol == Symbol.AndOperator || _symbol == Symbol.OrOperator) {
        var op = _symbol == Symbol.AndOperator
            ? BooleanOperator.And
            : BooleanOperator.Or;
        GetSymbol();
        term = ParseTerm();
        expression.SucceedingTerms.Add((op, term));
    }
    return expression;
}

// Term = "(" Expression ")" | Comparison.
void Term ParseTerm()
{
    Term term = null;
    if (Symbol == Symbol.LeftPar) {
        GetSymbol();
        term = ParseExpression();
        if (Symbol == Symbol.RightPar) {
            GetSymbol();
        } else {
            Error("\")\" expected.");
        }
    } else {
        term = ParseComparison();
    }
    return term;
}
```

This is not complete, but you get the idea. Since the structure of this parser depends on the syntax production (EBNF), do not start with it before you have nailed down the exact syntax.

Pay attention to always have decidable paths in the syntax given by the next symbol. First, I had it wrong. My term was given by `Term = "(" Expression | Comparison ")" | Comparison.`. The problem here is that an expression starts with a term and a term can be a comparison. The comparison starts with a name. Therefore, both `Expression` and `Comparison` can start with a name. When parsing  `Expression | Comparison` and the next symbol is a name, we are unable to decide whether we must parse an expression or a comparison.

The updated syntax is `Term = "(" Expression ")" | Comparison.`. Now, we know that if the next symbol is a left parenthesis, we must parse an expression and otherwise a comparison.

Comment: @Maulik. You will presumably have wished an easier solution, but there is no easy way to convert recursive expressions into recursive data structures. What do you think about my solution? Are there any ambiguities that I can clear up?

Comment: Thanks @Olivier for your your answer and help, you are right that we can't convert expression to recursive data structure directly, so based on your input and Servy's comment on this question, for now we have stopped translating to our custom class structure, and started translating Expression to individual NoSql, Cache etc. providers, for one of them we are able to retain nested condition with help of Visitor pattern, but still for other DB providers we need to solve this problem separately, as each is expecting different format to query. Thanks again for your follow-up help Olivier:)